# Windows 8.1 One Drive Won't Sync

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I just noticed something is wrong with my One Drive on my Windows 8 machine

I see this error

"Files can't be uploaded because we can't access one of your OneDrive folders on this PC"

I looked at the location in the properties(right clicked the one drive icon in my explorer) I see this

```
C:\Users\win8\SkyDrive
```

when I do restore default I get

```
C:\Users\win8\OneDrive
```

I try to apply this but it tries to move everthing over and hangs. I got some message of it can't access "Documents".

Not sure if this pathing is the problem or what.

Comment: Can you manually copy the content to a different folder?  Have you checked for file-system corruption?

Comment: What I did was I "cut" all the folders out of the "one drive" and let it resync, it downloaded everything again but now after I did that I get the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same symptom, which is probably a side effect of the rename of SkyDrive folder into OneDrive, combined with the fact the OneDrive folder is not at its default C:\Users...  location.
Here is how I fixed the issue.
I tried to view the contents of the OneDrive folder using the File Explorer. Then I got a Windows error message "You don't enough privileges to view the folder" (or something similar). However, the system also proposed me to get the missing access privileges... which I accepted. From then on, I could view the folder contents and so did the One Drive app.
Note this procedure probably requires to be logged on with administrative rights.